# Creating link from database table column to open a new database column views

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to ask a simple question, that incredibly bothers me and even while I have read few books and google and youtube it, I could not get a simple answer, so here it is:

in web form I am connect to SQL database, from that database I am retrieving data(rows and columns) of a .net table and I am able to save them to a table and then by selecting exact nuber of row and column work with each exact column - so I am able to create a nice view of a databe table

now imagine I have this nice view, lets say a "name of an article" and below that i have a "text of an article" - now the question - how do I make happen, that when the "name of an article" is clicked, user will open a full text of that one article on a new page.

example: i have a page which shows a summary of a two articles

```
dell studio nb
very good article about advantages of this masterpiece

imb thinkpad nb
in this article i show zou the latest pictures
```

When a user click on `dell studio nb` or `imb thinkpad nb` it should redirect him to see page like this:

```
imb thinkpad nb
as promised here are the pictures of this beautiful notebook and as zou can see etc.
```

Thank you very much in advance, have a great day.

Comment: I'm not sure you asked a question.

Comment: He asked a question.  My suggestion is to use an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the titles should be represented by hyperlink controls :

```
<asp:HyperLink id="title1" runat="server" 
NavigateUrl="~/FullText.aspx?Id=2" >imb thinkpad nb</asp:HyperLink>
```

Notice the `NavigateUrl` contains a [QueryString](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring), that should be the ID of the article stored in the database. when the page loads grab that Id and query the database for the full article.

Comment: great, the answer from AbZy works:) thank you man!

now I can finish the blog development.. :D